# Apache2 warning about NameVirtualHost directive

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-10.04

Can someone help me to understand why I receive the following errors when restarting my apache2 webserver:

```
[Fri Nov 09 09:46:43 2012] [warn] VirtualHost 172.30.30.12:443 overlaps with VirtualHost 172.30.30.12:443, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
[Fri Nov 09 09:46:43 2012] [warn] VirtualHost 172.30.30.12:443 overlaps with VirtualHost 172.30.30.12:443, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
```

The error always appears twice.  What is a NameVirtualHost directive?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have two `VirtualHost`s defined?

Comment: How would I check this?  What should I look for?

Comment: If this is the issue, someone would have to have put the `VirtualHost`s there. Do you use your web server, how did you configure it? You should have come across a `VirtualHost` at some point

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at [this example](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html#using).

You probably need to add this line to your Apache HTTP Server configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost 172.30.30.12:443
```

Comment: You may add `NameVirtualHost *:443` to enable for all IPs.